# How can I get the number of days something is overdue in this query?

Tags: mysql, datediff

I am trying to get a list of customers, films, and the number of days their rental was overdue (if that rental was kept longer than the rental duration).

For some reason, I am getting NULL for the number of days the rental was overdue using this query.

I got the tables from this resource:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-tables.html

Here is my query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, title, DATEDIFF(DATEDIFF(return_date,rental_date), rental_duration)
FROM sakila_customer 
JOIN sakila_rental USING (customer_id) 
JOIN sakila_inventory USING (inventory_id) 
JOIN sakila_film USING (film_id) 
WHERE sakila_film.rental_duration < DATEDIFF(sakila_rental.return_date,sakila_rental.rental_date);
```

Comment: What are the datatypes of all the `date` columns?

Comment: Type: datetime, NULL : NO, Key: MUL, Default: NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's returning null is because you're using `DATEDIFF` on values that are note dates.

Look at this line right here:

```
DATEDIFF(DATEDIFF(return_date, rental_date), rental_duration)
```

When you execute the inside (the difference between return and rental date) you will have an integer. rental_duration is also an integer, so when you try to do a datediff between them you get null, because you aren't taking the difference of dates.

So what you should do is get the datediff of return and rental date, and then subtract the rental duration from that. That number will give you the number of dates overdue.

Try this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, title, (DATEDIFF(return_date, rental_date) - rental_duration) AS daysOverdue
FROM customer
JOIN rental USING (customer_id)
JOIN inventory USING (inventory_id)
JOIN film USING (film_id)
WHERE rental_duration < DATEDIFF(return_date, rental_date);
```

I downloaded the database from your link and ran this in the MySQL workbench and achieved this result set:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will get a null if any of the values used to calculate the result are null.

Also, your expression doesn't look right, try:

```
Select ...
datediff(return_date, rental_date) - rental_duration overdue
from ...
...
where datediff(return_date, rental_date) - rental_duration > 0
```

Comment: when i try that it is saying Unknown column 'overdue' in 'where clause'

Comment: Now i am getting Error: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range

Comment: please provide sample actual values for the three columns return_date, rental_date and rental_duration

Comment: I put a link of the tables and the definition of each is in the link above.

Comment: rent_duration gives a int of number of days and return date and rental date gives the date and time that the item was rented and returned.